# Синхронизация в JS

Tags: javascript, async-await, callback, promise

Чтоб не устраивать очередной `callback-hell` и сделать код более плоским ищу аналог питоновского `loop.run_until_complete` для [js](/questions/tagged/js). Если вызывать промис из асинхронной функции, то можно воспользоваться `await`, но вызываться придётся из сторонних колбэков...

```
function main(){

let response_promise = axios.get("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random") 
// promise

let response = run_until_complete(response_promise) 
// готовый объект, который передается в .then()
}
```

Для асинхронных функций можно воспользоваться await:

```
async function async_main() {
   let response = await axios.get("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random")
}
```

При использовании калбэков и 2х запросов, зависимых друг от друга получается уже 3 колбэка. вот пример на 50 строк:

```
function onerror(error){
    console.log(error)
}

function onlogin(response) {
        if (response.redir.redirectionURL) {
            $window.location.href=response.redir.redirectionURL
        }
        else if (response.redir.originalURL) {
            $window.location.href=response.redir.originalURL
        } else {
            $location.path('/status/')
        }
}

function onchillistatus(response) {
    var challenge = hex2bin(response.challenge);
    var chapid = '\x00';

    var charpassw = hexMD5(chapid + password + challenge);
    $resource(chilli+'logon',
        {
            username:username,
            response:charpassw,
        },
        {get:{ method: 'JSONP',jsonpCallbackParam:'callback'}}
    ).get(onlogin);
}

function onmikrotikstatus(response){
        var dst = $cookies.get('linkorig') || "/uam/status/";

        if (response.challenge) {
          var charpassw = hexMD5(response.chapid + password + response.challenge);
        } else {
          var charpassw = password;
        }
        $resource($cookies.get('linklogin'),
        {
            target:'jsonp',
            dst:dst,
            username:username,
            password:charpassw,
        },
        {get:{ method: 'JSONP',jsonpCallbackParam:'var'}}).get(onlogin)
        if (response.redir.logoutURL) $cookies.put('linklogout', response.redir.logoutURL);
}

function login(){
      if(ischilli) {
          $resource(chilli+'status', { },
          {get:{ method: 'JSONP',jsonpCallbackParam:'callback'}}
          ).get(onchillistatus,onerror)
      } else {
          $resource($cookies.get('linklogin'),
          {
              target:'jsonp',
          },
          {get:{ method: 'JSONP',jsonpCallbackParam:'var'}}).get(onmikrotikstatus,onerror)

      }

}
```

Тут уже нельзя прочитать программу сверху вниз. И это только кусочек. А перед ним ещё пару запроса на получение логина и пароля с другого сервера. *Получается что нужно написать 7 функций на одно действие пользователя.*

Другой пример:

В vue компоненте указать валидатор, а валидатор должен сделать запрос в апи. Валидатор должен вернуть строку, но если положить туда асинхронную функцию, то он вернет промис.

Comment: а можно хотя бы псевдокод результата, который вы хотите увидеть? А то не очень понятно

Comment: чет понятней не стало, чем вам `await` не угодил? и что что вызовов несколько, два раз `await` напишите и все

Comment: [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) не рассматривали?

Comment: Promise.all() возвращает промис)

Comment: Авэйт не угодил только тем что работет только в асинхронной функции

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте `login` асинхронной и пишите там что хотите:

```
async function login() {
  if(ischilli) {
    const result = await fetchLogin();
    const result2 = await onmikrotikstatus(result);
  } else {
    const result = await fetchLogin();
    const result2 = await onlogin(result);
  }
}

// хотя код не дождется окончания самого login внутри будет все последовательно
login();
```

Если нужен `onerror`, то все в `catch`

```
async function login() {
  try {
    if(ischilli) {
      const result = await fetchLogin();
      const result2 = await onmikrotikstatus(result);
    } else {
      const result = await fetchLogin();
      const result2 = await onlogin(result);
    }
  } catch(error) {
    onerror(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Так и думаю, но на логин всеравно придется вешать колбэк

Comment: добавил второй пример, где такой подход не прокатит.